# Need Multiple IP addresses from one PC

Tags: networking, ip, user-accounts, isp, static-ip

I'm using it for online games and running programs for friends out of one PC. Limits will be placed soon, so my question is: how can I get a different IP address for each account loading up from one single PC. If they place a limit of two logins from one IP address, then we would need to run 10 logins from one PC, all with their own IP address.

Can this be done reasonably cheap?

Comment: Contact your ISP to understand the costs of this.

Comment: Talk to your ISP. Some of them offer plans that include multiple public IPs. Alternatively, you can look into a VPN service or make one yourself with an EC2 instance (or other VPS).

Comment: what exactly do you mean 10 logins? you mean 10 windows logins? 1 pc is going to have 1 ip address.

Comment: Not much of a tech person for PCs, but VPN won't work, those providers say I need to go Private Proxies. People needing this will only be able to login two accounts per IP address to the game. Most players now hold 10 to 40 accounts, which means that every two accounts will need their own IP address.....

Comment: It will be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: My ISP issues dynamic IP addresses, so I get a different IP address every time I reboot my router.  Getting multiple IP addresses would require you to get a business connection, which would cost a lot more than what you are currently paying.

Comment: @Sickets, a NIC can have multiple IPs and a PC can have multiple NICs. Most ISPs have an option to get additional static IPs, and that can range in price. The last ISP I did that with charged $5/mo per IP. The process for configuring multiple IP addresses on your NIC will vary based on your OS, but it is quite possible on Windows/*nix systems (depending on your config, you may need to ensure that IP routing tables are correct to ensure that traffic goes in and out on the correct IPs).

Answer (score 1):

A little late here, but I'll add it in case someone else finds this helpful.

IPv6 is what you're looking for. IPv6 enabled ISPs give each device a /64 prefix address from which you can pick any number of IP addresses.

That is, if you get a prefix of `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::/64`, you can assign any addresses from `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::1` to `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` to any device in your network.

---

Edit:

You can get an IPv4 too, if you connect to say 10 IPv4 enabled Wi-Fi hotspots, or if you add multiple IPv6 addresses to your network interface and set up IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnels on all of those IPs. For that you would either need 10 IPv4 enabled VPSes or a tunnel broker or VPN service.

Frankly it's hard to get many IPv4 tunnel providers since IPv4 addresses are running out. Maybe some VPN that supports both IPv4 and IPv6 like Cyberghost VPN can give you a IPv4 address, but there are not many IPv6 enabled VPNs and I'm not sure if it supports 4over6 tunneling. Also you would need 10 accounts so that's not a cheap solution either.

In short, getting an IPv6 enabled network provider is the cheapest way to go about this. The servers should support IPv6, but that's on them and it's better for them if they do.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you assign one IP address to each interface at a time. If I understand you correctly, you want to run 10 IP addresses at one time. That means you need 10 NICs which is rare for a desktop machine. Not to mention, your ISP will probably require you to get a Business Class service from them in order to get multiple public addresses through them.

Long story short: You can't easily do what you want to do, especially if you want it cheap.

Comment: You don't need 10 NICs to have 10 IP addresses.

Comment: True, but typically you do.

Comment: Why? I always just put them all on the same NIC, unless of course I need to worry about bandwidth - but if I'm reading/writing so much that I am over-powering a PC NIC, I'm probably beating the processor or HDD to death, so having multiple NICs would just be pointless.