# How to config Windows load balancing with multiple IP addresses on the same network interface?

Tags: windows, networking, ip, network-adapter

I'm using a network with a speed limit per IP. So I want to join multiple IP addresses to To increase Download speed.

Windows has this multi-IP option [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-8-computer)

[image: Windows multiple ip address configuration]

How can I Merge these IP addresses so I can use them simultaneously?

---

[Similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/712321/need-multiple-ip-addresses-from-one-pc?rq=1)

A way to bind an IP to a specific application [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/) or [Here](https://github.com/katlogic/bindip)

---

**[Update]**

I managed to download using two different IPs at the same time.

Using [ForceBindIp](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) V1.31 and assigning the second IP to Firefox, I manage to download simultaneously.

[image: Download using multiple IP addresses]

*Now I just need a load-balancing system to put together these connections. (My idea is to find a load-balancing proxy client!)*

---

**[Answer for windows server 2008 (Or maybe 7 and 8)]**

Using windows server 2008 (Or maybe 7 and 8) you can use [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725691(v=ws.11).aspx) to actually solve this problem. But as I am on Windows 10, I can't really use that article.
*(Don't know really if it work on the same network adapter!)*

Comment: It is not so easy. If you manage to get your machine two IPs you could set up some tunneling/loadbalancing solution but this does require a endpoint and the result might be disappointing. Not to mention IT Security group will kill you if the find out.

Comment: I can assign multiple IP addresses, But i need to force applications using them. Any idea how to tunnel them ? @eckes

Comment: Is the speed limit actually less than what the single link can carry? Even if you assign multiple IPs to one interface you won't be able to exceed the link speed. You would need to look into aggregation in order to use them both but that usually uses multiple, physical adapters. Alternatively you would need to find a way to tell a program which adapter to use which isn't done easily either.

Comment: @Seth Yes This can work. there are programs like vmware so bridge your network and they are working on my case. please think of the way so i can merge these IP addresses.

Comment: My comment actually contains the technical term of what you're trying to do. So you will have to check into it yourself. In addition a network bridge like the one VMware and VirtualBox create are ever so slightly different. After all your guest only sees a virtual interface and uses that for network access. Tough certain information between the physical and virtual interface are passed back and forth. The hypervisor takes care of actually patching it through to the network layer.

Comment: @Seth Alright, so what makes me stop adding that layer ? http://speedify.com/ Does that (kind of)

Comment: So you have a solution? Than use it? Did I say at any point that something would stop you from doing this? But just in case it's not clear: You're not looking for a bridging solution. You're looking for a link aggregation solution (NIC Teaming) for multiple IPs on the same physical interface. Which usually doesn't work because it's not operating on an IP level. Even the "solution" (a VPN) you linked doesn't do anything it that regard. it merely create a virtual interface which you can get for free with OpenVPN. Though you would have to setup the server yourself.

Comment: well that ip binder can't bind ip from the same network !  the speedify merges your different connections (wifi, data,lan) @Seth

Answer (score 0):

> Is it theoretically possible?: **Yes** (By combining [ForceBindIP](https://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/),
>   a Proxy and a Load Balance Engine).
>
> Is it possible Now?: **No!**

The only way to **MERGE** them in windows is **"[NIC Team](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831648(v=ws.11).aspx)"** available in *Windows Server 2012* and up, ***which needs multiple "Link Per Interface"***, (Check [Here](http://www.youritsource.org/msft/how-to-enable-nic-teaming-in-windows-8-8-1-and-10/) and [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/955825/is-windows-10-software-nic-teaming-now-possible) if you want to enable it on windows 8, 8.1, 10...) and in expensive network infrastructure devices you find "**[Link Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)**" which virtually works the same way. As stated by [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771274(v=ws.11).aspx) the idea of assigning multiple IP addresses to one interface in windows was to eliminate the need of changing IP address in case you routinely migrate to different networks (e.g. Home, office, cafe...), or when you need more than 1 IP on the same network (e.g. accessing two different subnets). But, there are expensive infrastructures where you can randomly, or conditionally, load balance your traffic between a pool of IPs (e.g. [Source NAT Pool](http://www.jnpr.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1x46/topics/concept/nat-security-source-pool-understanding.html) in Juniper networks).

Comment: NIC Teams and bonding work below the IP layer

Comment: @eckes I know, but the title is too generic and maybe someone looking for link aggregation end up here.

Comment: agree it is good to mention it, but it's not what the original asker needs. At least not what Heins looking for as the limit is on an IP level (supposedly)

Comment: @eckes I agree on that, so it deserves a down vote. viel Spaß! :)

Comment: Hay @AmirHossein, I looked at your articles, it seems that they can join two adapters, but as I explained I have one adapter having multiple IP addresses. What do you say ?

Comment: @AmirHossein havent downvoted it, just want to make sure the scope of the answer is understood, maybe you can edit it in

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah Updated my answer.

Comment: @eckes I did my best to put it into scope... I didn't say you downvoted. However, you have the right to downvote :)

Comment: I'm really sorry @AmirHossein new version of ForceBindIp really worked. (older versions i tested before didn't) All I need is a load balancing system. if you make it all together, The answer will be yours.

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah You can use scripts instead shortcuts to launch applications with ForceBindIP, but you still can't aggregate them. For example you can't use both IPs to download using IDM. I believe it's totally possible and even easy to accomplish, but it needs some programmer attention. Maybe you can contact the developers and ask them to add multi-IP load-balancing.

Answer (score -1):

From the instructions you linked, it looks like you hit add in the top box and put in another ip address in the same range. But, if the network uses DHCP to assign addresses, that will possibly lead to conflicts. Try using a high number like .235 as the last part of the ip address if that happens.

Otherwise, you need 2 network cards with one ip each.

In my experience, Windows isn't good at aggregating links. You might also need software such as Speedify (speedify.com)

Comment: Well i have no problem assigning an ip address. i just need to use more than one at once.

Comment: Not possible with TCP without some intermediate layer.

Comment: Alright all I want is that layer, Windows provides the basics and Vmware is using it to create bridges, So i want to do that (Any how) @eckes

Comment: The suggestion about using high IPs is rather bad without knowing any more about the network configuration.